# How to build a PDF using xelatex.exe from command line (Windows)?

Tags: errors, xetex, build-system

I am trying to build a `.pdf` from a `.tex` file using `xelatex.exe` and it does not work. I tried something like this:

```
xelatex.exe -enable-installer file.tex
```

And this gives some errors:

```
Sorry, but xelatex.exe did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
```

How can I build a `.pdf` file using the command line and also allow installation of the missing packages and update the FNDB?

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: check the answers in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24291/execute-xelatex

Comment: Try out with a hello-world.tex and without the option -enable-installer. Does this work?

Comment: Without enable-installer works ok. The command line say that can not process the command line input: **2018-05-24 15:13:46,865+0300 FATAL xelatex - The command line options could not be processed.
2018-05-24 15:13:46,866+0300 FATAL xelatex - Info: optionError="unknown option"**